# Is there a way to make the transition property work for a javascript selected item?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

Is there a way to have a smooth transition between two states of an element if javascript is selector is used? For example, I have an element with the class of click__box and the id of clickBox. I can set the opacity from 0 to 1 when the button is clicked by using JS. The problem is that transition property has no effect at all. I know that it can be used something like the checkbox hack with pure css but i would like to know if there is a way of doing this with JavaScript.

```
//CSS
.click__box {
width:100%;
height:100%;
opacity:0;
transition:all .5s;
}
//JS
const collectionButton = document.querySelector("#collectionButton")
var clickBoxStyle = document.getElementById("clickBox").style

collectionButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   clickBoxStyle.opacity = "1"
})
```

Comment: I've copied and tried the code you've posted, and the transition actually does work for me. Is there a specific browser you're having issues in? Could you post your HTML too?

Comment: Please include the HTML on which this acts in an [mre]; you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It works well.

```js
const collectionButton = document.querySelector("#collectionButton")
var clickBoxStyle = document.getElementById("clickBox").style

collectionButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  clickBoxStyle.opacity = "1"
})
```

```css
.click__box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  background-color: GREEN;
}

#collectionButton {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="collectionButton">
  collectionButton click me
</div>

<div class="container">
  Click Box Container
  <div id="clickBox" class="click__box">
    Click Box
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo for you pal https://codepen.io/init1/pen/mddKgyw